# How can I produce the element with the largest sum of each integer in the string?

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
//  Produce the element with largest sum of each integer in the string.
var phoneList1 = ["111-111-1113", "111-111-1113", "111-111-1111", "111-111-1112"];

for (var i = 0; i < phoneList1.length; i++) {           // Iterating through the array
    phoneList1[i] = phoneList1[i].replace(/-/g, '');    // Removing the dashes (-)
    phoneList1[i] = parseInt(phoneList1[i], 10);        // Converting to integers   
}
```

This is as far as I've gotten.

Given an array of phone numbers, how can I find the item in the list which when each number in the string is added together is the largest of all the items in the list.

Example: `"111-111-1111" = 10`

Comment: Could you clarify the function of this method? What do you mean by "element with largest sum of contiguous integers" when you're parsing phone numbers? What is the expected output for your sample input?

Comment: what is your desired out output?? **111-111-1113** OR **1111111113** OR something else ?

Comment: Split phone number by **-** and convert each element of array to number and sum all.  If sum is greater than previous some store it as result otherwise to next iteration.

Comment: Thank-you for asking. This is an interview question from a local boot-camp. The task is to take an array of phone numbers and return _only_ the phone number who's integers, when added together are greater than the individual sum of each other phone number in the array. For example when the integers of phone number 111-111-1111 are added together it will sum 10. The number 111-111-1112 when added will sum 11. Therefore, the second phone number is the greater. My question is: How do I add them after I remove the dash and change them from strings to integers?

Comment: @AndyYoung You might want to add that information to the question itself and see if it can be reopened.

Comment: I added a better explanation in my edit of the question.  Also, these are not contiguous numbers, you are taking them each as individual numbers and summing them.  Contiguous would be (1,2,3,4,5).  Non-contiguous would be (1,3,10, 2).  This is... as far as I am aware.  I adjusted the question to ask this taking this into account.  I also believe I have an answer for this.

Comment: [This?](https://jsfiddle.net/tvt6v2vd/3/)

Answer (score 0):

You open up the console of your browser and paste the code below:

```js
var phoneList1 = ["111-111-1113", "111-111-1113", "111-111-1111", "111-111-1112"];

//this function returns the largest sum
function mainWithTrack(phoneBook){
  //number is a string with integers and dashes(or other chars)
  function convertNumberToInt(number){
    var numberDigits = number.split('');
    var sum = 0;
    numberDigits.forEach(function(number){
       if (parseInt(number)){
         sum += parseInt(number);
       }
    });
    return sum;
  }
  var convertedPhoneBook = phoneBook.map(function(phoneNumber, index){
      return { number: convertNumberToInt(phoneNumber), index: index };
  });
  function compareNumbers(a, b) {
    return a.number - b.number;
  }
  return convertedPhoneBook.sort(compareNumbers)[phoneBook.length-1];
}
//now call it 
var largest = mainWithTrack(phoneList1);
console.log("Largest sum is ", largest.number, " at index ", largest.index, " in phoneList1: ", phoneList1[largest.index]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Below works for your case:

```js
var pn = [
  0,
  "more invalid numbers",
  "111-111-111",
  "111-111-112",
  "111-111-115",
  "111-711-111",
  "111-111-113",
  1,
  "invalid"
];

// String summing function
function sumPN(s) {
  if (typeof(s) !== "string")
    return 0;
  return s.split("").reduce(function(r, n) {
    // All non-digits are set to 0
    r = parseInt(r);
    n = parseInt(n);
    if (isNaN(r))
      r = 0;
    if (isNaN(n))
      n = 0;
    return r+n;
  });
}

function getLarge(a) {
  var sum = 0;
  return a[a.reduce(function(large, cur, idx) {
    // convert first element
    if (idx === 1) {
      sum = sumPN(large);
      large = 0;
    };

    // parse all the rest, compare, set new index and sum where necessary
    curSum = sumPN(cur);
    console.log(curSum, cur);
    if (curSum > sum) {
      sum = curSum;
      return idx;
    }
    return large
  })];
}
document.write(getLarge(pn));
```